# Sorting objects by secondary key when first is equal

Tags: ruby

How can I sort multiple objects by a secondary key when the first one is equal?

In my `Book` class I have the following method used for sorting

```
def <=>(other)
  printed_on <=> other.printed_on
end
```

Now I need the books printed the same day (`printed_on = other.printed_on`) to be sorded by `page_number`.

Since with `sort_by` you can pass an array of keys, I have tried

```
 def <=>(other)
   [printed_on <=> other.printed_on, page_number <=> other.page_number]
 end
```

but I get

> undefined method `>' for [1, 1]:Array

Comment: Your sorting scheme seems to be very specific. Instead of hard-coding it into the `Book` class, you could also sort the books on the caller's side, e.g. `array_of_books.sort_by { |b| [b.printed_on, b.page_number] }`.

Comment: I’m working on a legacy app with sort_by all over the places. In many cases they sort by different attributes even if they should all sort by the same ones. I feel adding a default sorting (and removing all the sort_by around) will make cose cleaner and more consistent. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[`Array`s are compared lexicographically](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) (**bold** emphasis mine):

> Arrays are compared in an “element-wise” manner; **the first element of `ary` is compared with the first one of `other_ary`** using the `<=>` operator, **then each of the second elements**, etc… As soon as the result of any such comparison is non zero (i.e. the two corresponding elements are not equal), that result is returned for the whole array comparison.

[This is just a convoluted way of saying "`Array`s are compared lexicographically".]

So you could simply use an `Array` for your comparison:

```rb
def <=>(other)
  [printed_on, page_number] <=> [other.printed_on, other.page_number]
end
```

Your method violates [the contract of `<=>`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) (**bold** emphasis mine):

> Your implementation of `#<=>` should return one of the following values: `-1`, `0`, `1` or `nil`.

There are only four allowed return values for a conforming implementation of `<=>`:

- `-1`: less-than
- `0`: equal
- `+1`: greater-than
- `nil`: uncomparable (partially ordered)

You are returning neither of those four, you are returning an `Array`. As always, if you break the contract, strange things can happen.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for:

```
[printed_on, page_number] <=> [other.printed_on, other.page_number]
```

`<=>` has to return a number (conventionally it should be 1, 0 or 1, however ruby allows any numeric value) or nil if comparison is not possible). Your implementation returns an array of two numbers which causing the issue as it is trying to compare said array with 0.

Comment: "`<=>` has to return a number" – This is wrong. It is both too general and too specific. First off, it cannot return *any* number, it can only return `-1`, `0`, or `+1`. Secondly, it is also allowed to return `nil`, which is not a number. This is specified in [the method contract of `<=>`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E).

Comment: @JörgWMittag - Ther are quite  afew objects that implements it so it returns non [-1, 0, 1] numbers which is why Comparable module is just comparing the value with 0. While this is convention it should return those values, it seems ruby only seems to be interested in its posiivity/negativity. Kudos on `nil`, will update the answer.

Comment: _"even though Array implements <=> it does not include Comparable module"_ – that sounds as if including `Comparable` would turn arrays into valid return values for `<=>` (which is not the case).

Comment: @Stefan - Good spot, the wording is a bit out of place. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You can also chain the comparisons via [`nonzero?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F) and `||`:

```
def <=>(other)
  (printed_on <=> other.printed_on).nonzero? || page_number <=> other.page_number
end
```

The expression returns `printed_on <=> other.printed_on` if its result is non-zero, and `page_number <=> other.page_number` otherwise.

You might want to add a guard clause for non-`Book` objects:

```
def <=>(other)
  return nil unless other.is_a?(Book)

  (printed_on <=> other.printed_on).nonzero? || page_number <=> other.page_number
end
```